# Testing PostgreSQL functions that consume and return refcursor

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-cursor

I want to test results of a Postgres function (changing the function is not a possibility).

The function receives as arguments a REFCURSOR and several other things and returns the same RECURSOR.

```
get_function_that_returns_cursor(ret, 4100, 'SOMETHING', 123465)
```

Now I want to create a small test in Postgres to get the results of this FUNCTION.
Something Like the code below (this is my approach but it is not working):

```
DO $$ DECLARE
 ret REFCURSOR; 
 row_to_read table_it_will_return%ROWTYPE ;
BEGIN
 PERFORM get_function_that_returns_cursor(ret, 4100, 'SOMETHING', 123465);
-- OR SELECT get_function_that_returns_cursor(ret, 4100, 'SOMETHING', 123465) INTO ret
 FOR row_to_read IN SELECT * FROM ret LOOP
   -- (...)
   RAISE NOTICE 'Row read...';
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE ret;
END $$;
```

Any suggestion on how to get this to work? A generic solution that can be used for testing this type of functions (that get a Cursor and return a Cursor?

And if we don't know the rowtype that is being returned how could we do it?

Comment: Working with dynamic rowsets is difficult in PL/PgSQL. It doesn't really deal well with them. I'd recommend consuming the refcursor in a pl/python, pl/perl, etc function and doing your testing and evaluation there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Q1

Your "small test" can be plain SQL:

```sql
BEGIN;
SELECT get_function_that_returns_cursor('ret', 4100, 'foo', 123); -- note: 'ret'
FETCH ALL IN ret; -- works for any rowtype

COMMIT;  -- or ROLLBACK;
```

Execute `COMMIT` / `ROLLBACK` *after* you inspected the results. Most clients only display the result of the lat command.

More in the chapter [**Returning Cursors**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html#AEN57066) of the manual.

#### Q2

> And if we don't know the rowtype that is being returned how could we do it?

Since you only want to inspect the results, you could **cast the whole record to `text`**.
This way you avoid the problem with dynamic return types for the function altogether.

Consider this demo:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (a_id int PRIMARY KEY, a text);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar');


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reffunc(INOUT ret refcursor)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   OPEN ret FOR SELECT * FROM a;
END
$func$;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ctest()
  RETURNS SETOF text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   curs1 refcursor;
   rec   record;
BEGIN
   curs1 := reffunc('ret');   -- simple assignment
  
   LOOP
      FETCH curs1 INTO rec;
      EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;    -- note the placement!
      RETURN NEXT rec::text;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b88d5b2d49deddb679ff5fe4799bf473)*
<sub>[Old sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/64bc8/1)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

This worked for what I wanted:

```
DO $$ DECLARE
 mycursor REFCURSOR;
 rec RECORD;
BEGIN
 SELECT 'ret' INTO mycursor FROM get_function_that_returns_cursor('ret'::REFCURSOR, 4100, 'SOMETHING', 123465);
 WHILE (FOUND) LOOP
   FETCH mycursor INTO rec;
   RAISE NOTICE 'Row read. Data: % ', rec.collumn_name;
 END LOOP;
END $$
```