# Correct way of calling reference cursors in PostgreSQL 11 and above using JDBC driver

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-11, ref-cursor

I need some suggestion on how to get the data through PostgreSQL JDBC driver from stored procedures using reference cursors.

Since PostgreSQL 11, it supports stored procedures with `create procedure` command instead of `create function`.

I have a scenario in which I want to fetch data from a stored procedure using a reference cursor.

My stored procedure SQL looks like as shown below

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.pr_sampleuser(
    p_firstuser character varying,
    INOUT p_qusers refcursor)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$

BEGIN
   OPEN p_qusers FOR
   SELECT first_name,last_name,address
   FROM public.test_user
   WHERE UPPER(first_name) = UPPER(p_firstuser);
END; 
$BODY$;
```

When we want to fetch the data using the JDBC driver, the first thing we need to add to the connection string is `escapeSyntaxCallMode=call`.

Following is the code-snippet that I am using to fetch the data,

```java
try {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("escapeSyntaxCallMode", "call");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,props);
    String storedProc = "{call public.pr_sampleuser(?,?)}";
    CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(storedProc);
    cs.setString(1,"Umesh");
    cs.setObject(2,null);
    cs.registerOutParameter(2,Types.REF_CURSOR);
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);

    // run StoredProcedure
    cs.execute();

    // get refcursor and convert it to ResultSet
    ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(2);
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        String firstName = resultSet.getString("first_name");
        String lastname = resultSet.getString("last_name");
        String address = resultSet.getString("address");

        System.out.println(firstName);
        System.out.println(lastname);
        System.out.println(address);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this I am passing the second parameter as null using

```java
cs.setObject(2,null);
```

I wanted to check if this is the correct way to fetch or if there is any better way to get the data.

Comment: This would be so much easier if you use a set-returning function instead of a procedure. Then it's as simple as running `select * from pr_sampleuser()`

Comment: does this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671636/testing-postgresql-functions-that-consume-and-return-refcursor/15675036#15675036) answer your question...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: sry but i am not looking for workrounds, consider that aspect that procedure is already created for you, i am asking for how to access it correctly using JDBC.
Jian: The post you have mentioned is about stored proc creation and calling it, i am looking forward to access the data through JDBC driver and it this is the best way to read the data.

Comment: Well, a procedure is the wrong thing to use, if a result set should be returned. Using a function is not a "workaround", it's the correct solution to the problem here.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: See thats another aspect, but the procedures have already been created and i believe its not wrong as per https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/jdbc_connector/latest/08_advanced_jdbc_connector_functionality/04_using_ref_cursors_with_java/

Comment: Does it work? If so, this seems to be the correct solution, and then I am unsure why you're asking this question...

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: yes this solution works, my concern was around why we need to use cs.setObject(2,null); Is it that for referenceCursors we need to set the value of 2nd parameter to null or if there is any better way of doing this?

Comment: You need to set it because you declared the argument of the stored procedure as INOUT. Consider declaring it only OUT, then you shouldn't need to set it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: That is true, just that PostGres13 doesn't support Out Parameters, i think they are available only with PostGres version 14 , https://www.dbi-services.com/blog/postgresql-14-will-support-out-parameters-for-procedures/